# How to create AWS Cognito stack using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm new to aws cloudformation and the cdk. I'm trying to create a sample stack just to try things out and I keep getting this error:  "Invalid Cognito Identity Provider (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 7db28b4b-373b-4808-9c8d-1d197b0be542; Proxy: null)"

My code:

```
const cdk = require('aws-cdk-lib');
const ec2 = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2');
const apigateway = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway');
const cognito = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-cognito');
const iam = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam');
const { Stack } = require('aws-cdk-lib');

class MyCdkStack extends Stack {
  /**
   *
   * @param {Construct} scope
   * @param {string} id
   * @param {StackProps=} props
   */
  constructor(scope, id, props) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create a VPC for the EC2 instance
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'MyVPC', {
      maxAzs: 2 // Use 2 availability zones
    });

    const sg = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'MySSHSecurityGroup', {
      vpc,
      description: 'Allow Outbound SSH access',
      securityGroupName: 'My SSH Security Group',
      allowAllOutbound: true // Allow all outbound traffic
    });

    // Allow SSH access from a specific IP range
    sg.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.ipv4('anipaddress/32'), ec2.Port.tcp(22), 'Allow inbound SSH access from here');
    sg.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.ipv4('anipaddress/32'), ec2.Port.tcp(22), 'Allow inbound SSH access from here 2');

    /////////////////////

    // Create a Cognito user pool
    const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, 'MyUserPool', {
      userPoolName: 'My User Pool',
      selfSignUpEnabled: true,
      autoVerify: { email: true },
      signInAliases: { email: true },
      passwordPolicy: {
        minLength: 8,
        requireDigits: true,
        requireLowercase: true,
        requireUppercase: true,
        requireSymbols: true
      }
    });

    const userPoolClient = new cognito.CfnUserPoolClient(this, "MyUserPoolClient", {
      userPoolId: userPool.ref,
      explicitAuthFlows: ["ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH"],
      generateSecret: false,
      readAttributes: [
        "preferred_username",
        "website",
        "email",
        "name",
        "zoneinfo",
        "phone_number",
        "phone_number_verified",
        "email_verified",
      ],
      writeAttributes: ["name", "zoneinfo", "phone_number"],
    });

    // Create a Cognito identity pool
    const identityPool = new cognito.CfnIdentityPool(this, 'MyIdentityPool', {
      identityPoolName: 'My Identity Pool',
      allowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false,
      cognitoIdentityProviders: [{
        clientId: userPoolClient.ref,
        providerName: userPool.userPoolProviderName,
      }]
    });

    // Create an API Gateway REST API
    const restApi = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'MyRestApi', {
      restApiName: 'My Rest API',
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'prod'
      }
    });

    const sg2 = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'MyAPIGatewaySecurityGroup', {
      vpc,
      description: 'Allow port 80 traffic from the API Gateway',
      securityGroupName: 'My API Gateway Security Group',
      allowAllOutbound: true // Allow all outbound traffic
    });

    // Allow port 80 traffic from the API Gateway
    sg2.addIngressRule(
      ec2.Peer.ipv4(`${restApi.restApiId}.execute-api.${cdk.Stack.of(this).region}.amazonaws.com/32`),
      ec2.Port.tcp(80),
      'Allow port 80 traffic from the API Gateway'
    );

    const keyName = 'my-key-pair';

    // Create an EC2 key pair for SSH access
    const key = new ec2.CfnKeyPair(this, 'MyKeyPair', {
      keyName,
    });

    // Associate the key pair with the EC2 instance
    const instance = new ec2.Instance(this, 'MyEC2Instance', {
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
      machineImage: new ec2.AmazonLinuxImage(),
      vpc,
      securityGroup: sg2,
      key,
      userData: ec2.UserData.custom(`
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "Hello, world!" > /var/www/html/index.html
      `)
    });

    // Create a Cognito authorizer
    const authorizer = new apigateway.CfnAuthorizer(this, 'MyCognitoAuthorizer', {
      name: 'My-Cognito-Authorizer',
      identitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization',
      restApiId: restApi.restApiId,
      type: apigateway.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
      providerArns: [userPool.userPoolArn]
    });

    // Create a resource and method for the API Gateway and Add the Cognito authorizer to the method
    const resource = restApi.root.addResource('my-resource');
    const method = resource.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.HttpIntegration(`http://${instance.instancePublicIp}`),
      {
        authorizationType: apigateway.AuthorizationType.COGNITO, authorizer: authorizer
      });

    // Create an IAM role for authenticated users
    const authenticatedRole = new iam.Role(this, 'MyAuthenticatedRole', {
      assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal('cognito-identity.amazonaws.com', {
        StringEquals: { 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud': identityPool.ref },
        'ForAnyValue:StringLike': { 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': 'authenticated' }
      }, 'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity')
    });

    // Create an IAM role for unauthenticated users
    const unauthenticatedRole = new iam.Role(this, 'MyUnauthenticatedRole', {
      assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal('cognito-identity.amazonaws.com', {
        StringEquals: { 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud': identityPool.ref },
        'ForAnyValue:StringLike': { 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': 'unauthenticated' }
      }, 'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity')
    });

    // Grant permissions to the authenticated role
    authenticatedRole.addToPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: [
        'execute-api:Invoke'
      ],
      resources: [
        method.methodArn
      ]
    }));

    // Grant permissions to the unauthenticated role
    unauthenticatedRole.addToPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: [
        'cognito-identity:GetId',
        'cognito-identity:GetOpenIdToken'
      ],
      resources: [
        `arn:aws:cognito-identity:${this.region}:${this.account}:identitypool/${identityPool.ref}`
      ]
    }));

    // Set the roles for authenticated and unauthenticated users
    new cognito.CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment(this, 'MyIdentityPoolRoles', {
      identityPoolId: identityPool.ref,
      roles: {
        authenticated: authenticatedRole.roleArn,
        unauthenticated: unauthenticatedRole.roleArn
      }
    });
  }
}

module.exports = { MyCdkStack }

// const app = new cdk.App();
// new MyStack(app, 'MyStack');
```

EDIT (Added screenshot):[image]

Comment: look at the cloudformation stack (make sure you show deleted stacks if it's rolled back on create failed).  In "events" or "resources" you can see which resource has the problem.  That can narrow it down to one resource.

Comment: Ya i've manually deleted the stacks through the console including all the resources the the script creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a more up-to-date example. Perhaps:

```
    const userPoolWebClient = new cognito.UserPoolClient(
  this,
  'userPoolWebClient',
  {
    userPool: userPool,
    generateSecret: false,
    preventUserExistenceErrors: true,
    authFlows: {
      userPassword: true,
      userSrp: true,
    },
    oAuth: {
      flows: {
        authorizationCodeGrant: false,
        implicitCodeGrant: true,
      },
    },
  },
);

new core.CfnOutput(this, 'UserPoolWebClientId', {
  value: userPoolWebClient.userPoolClientId,
});

const identityPool = new cognito.CfnIdentityPool(
  this,
  'DashboardIdentityPool',
  {
    cognitoIdentityProviders: [
      {
        clientId: userPoolWebClient.userPoolClientId,
        providerName: `cognito-idp.${this.region}.amazonaws.com/${userPool.userPoolId}`,
      },
    ],
    allowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true,
  },
);
```

Comment: what is the
```
new core.CfnOutput(this, 'UserPoolWebClientId', {
  value: userPoolWebClient.userPoolClientId,
});
```

I tried and synth just errored out on me.